# Given a range find the sum of number that is divisible by 3 or 5

Tags: c

The below code that works perfectly fine for smaller digits, But Time dilation for greater digits
given me the suggestion

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main()
{
  int num;
  int sum=0;
  scanf("%d",&num);
  for(int i=1;i<=num;i++)
  {
    if(i%3==0 || i%5==0)
    sum += i;
  }
  printf("%d",sum);
}
```

Need efficient code for this

Try to reduce the time take for the code.

Comment: You could start the loop from (int i = 3). Will save you just a few iterations, but can't think of any other substantial way to optimize this code. Could also swap (i++) to (++i). If the problem was to find all numbers that are divisible by 3 and 5, you could reduce the if statement to (i % 15 == 0).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The answer can be computed with simple arithmetic without any iteration. Many Project Euler questions are intended to make you think about clever ways to find solutions without just using the raw power of computers to chug through calculations. (This was [Project Euler question 1](https://projecteuler.net/problem=1), except the Project Euler problem specifies the limit using less than instead of less than or equal to.)

Given positive integers *N* and *F*, the number of positive multiples of *F* that are less than or equal to *N* is ⌊*N*/*F*⌋. (⌊*x*⌋ is the greatest integer not greater than *x*.) For example, the number of multiples of 5 less than or equal to 999 is ⌊999/5⌋ = ⌊199.8⌋ = 199.

Let *n* be this number of multiples, ⌊*N*/*F*⌋.

The first multiple is *F* and the last multiple is *n*•*F*. For example, with 1000 and 5, the first multiple is 5 and the last multiple is 200•5 = 1000.

The multiples are evenly spaced, so the average of all of them equals the average of the first and the last, so it is (*F* + *n**F*)/2.

The total of the multiples equals their average multiplied by the number of them, so the total of the multiples of *F* less than *N* is *n* • (*F* + *n*•*F*)/2.

Adding the sum of multiples of 3 and the sum of multiples of 5 includes the multiples of both 3 and 5 twice. We can correct for this by subtracting the sum of those numbers. Multiples of both 3 and 5 are multiples of 15.

Thus, we can compute the requested sum using simple arithmetic without any iteration:

```
#include <stdio.h>


static long SumOfMultiples(long N, long F)
{
    long NumberOfMultiples = N / F;
    long FirstMultiple = F;
    long LastMultiple = NumberOfMultiples * F;

    return NumberOfMultiples * (FirstMultiple + LastMultiple) / 2;
}


int main(void)
{
    long N = 1000;
    long Sum = SumOfMultiples(N, 3) + SumOfMultiples(N, 5) - SumOfMultiples(N, 3*5);

    printf("%ld\n", Sum);
}
```

As you do other Project Euler questions, you should look for similar ideas.

Comment: It's probably worth mentioning that this only works because 3 and 5 are coprime.

Comment: Note that `NumberOfMultiples * (FirstMultiple + LastMultiple) / 2` is just `F * (NumberOfMultiples * (NumberOfMultiples  + 1) / 2)`, i.e. it's `F` times the sum of all integers from `1` through `NumberOfMultiples `.  This avoids an intermediate result that's larger than the final result (when `F` is greater than `1`).

Comment: @TomKarzes: I wrote the code for clarity of exposition. `NumberOfMultiples * (FirstMultiple + LastMultiple) / 2;` mirrors the preceding text explanation of how we use the known average of the numbers to calculate their total.

Comment: @EricPostpischil That makes sense.  I think of it as a simple sum of integers, scaled by `F` (e.g. 3+6+9+... = 3*(1+2+3...), which seemed simplest to me.

Comment: @IanAbbott: You may be assuming 15 was chosen because it is the product of 3 and 5. However, the answer does not say that. The property is stated as “Multiples of both 3 and 5 are multiples of 15.” No general case is stated; I tailored this answer for the specific question asked by OP, showing how we can calculate each sum without iteration and how we can use the inclusion-exclusion principle to combine them. Generalizing would have complicated the answer. For non-coprime numbers, say 6 and 10, we would have “Multiples of both 6 and 10 are multiples of 30,” using the least common multiple.

Comment: @EricPostpischil Indeed, and the problem gets more interesting when the cardinality of the set of divisors to check is greater than 2. Because you need to check the LCM of every subset (except the empty set) and add or subtract the number of multiples of each LCM according to whether the cardinality of the subset is odd or even.